# Use 2 values passed AJAX in a SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, ajax

This is on an IIS 7.5 Classic ASP website using a SQL Server 2012 database.

I need help. I am passing 2 values through a function to another classic asp page that in turn will use those values in a SQL statement to return a value

When I use this, it does not return values but when I enter a value manually, like a '7' for `UnitPieces` and 'Los Angeles' for `City`, it returns the proper data from the SQL Server database.

Here is what I am working with

```
<form>
<select id="shiptoarea" name="shipcost" class="required" onchange="shipping(this.value)">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">--Choose One--</option>
<option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
<option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="New York">New York</option>
<option value="San Diego">San Digeo</option>
</select>
</form>
<p id="shippingcost"></p>
```

Which sends the value to this AJAX function *(Note: <%=vcItems%> is the number of items in the shopping cart)*

```
function shipping(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            document.getElementById("shippingcost").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "shiptoamount.asp?y=<%=vcItems%>&q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And this is the page that runs the SQL query

```
Dim Connection
Dim ConnString
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL
Dim qq
Dim yy

qq = (request.querystring("q"))
yy = (request.querystring("y"))

ConnString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLServerName;UID=username;" & _ 
"PWD=password;DATABASE=databasename"

SQL = "SELECT FlatShipCost FROM ShipRates WHERE UnitPieces = "&yy&" AND City = "&qq

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Connection.Open ConnString

Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

If Recordset.EOF Then 
    Response.Write("No records returned.") 
Else 
    if NOT Recordset.Eof then
        Response.write (request.querystring("q"))
        Response.write (Recordset("FlatShipCost"))
    end if
End if

Recordset.Close
Set Recordset = nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection = nothing
```

The strange thing is that if I manually

```
Response.write (request.querystring("q"))
```

or

```
Response.write (request.querystring("y"))
```

IT DOES display the HTML for the `City` selected from the dropdown and also the correct number of items in the cart from <%=vcItems%>. So the values ARE getting to the page running the query but I think I might be doing something wrong with the SQL statement. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Beware of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just miss the quotes to pass the string qq to the city condition:

```
SQL = "SELECT FlatShipCost FROM ShipRates WHERE UnitPieces = "&yy&" AND City = '"&qq&"';"
```

Comment: thank you for responding, Falco. I tried your recommendation and no dice yet :(

Comment: check that! i had a typo! That did it sir! Thank you very much, Falco!!!!